# Difference in return f(x) and return (f(x))

Tags: lua

What's difference
`return f(x)`
and
`return (f(x))`

preferably in sense of logical parsing

Comment: From the manual: Any expression enclosed in parentheses always results in only one value. Thus, (f(x,y,z)) is always a single value, even if f returns several values. (The value of (f(x,y,z)) is the first value returned by f or nil if f does not return any values.)   please read the manual. this is mentioned several times across various chapters.

Answer (score 8):

A function in Lua can return any number of values (0,1,2,...)

`return f(x)` means "calculate f(x) and return all values returned by the function"
`return (f(x))` means "calculate f(x) and return only the first value returned by the function, return `nil` if no values were returned"

That's why `return f(x)` can be compiled as a tail call but `return (f(x))` can not.